Geometry Node group to efficiently find a common edge between two faces
I'm looking to create a node setup that can simply output, given two faces indices, if the two faces share an edge, and if so, what the index of that edge is.
The only way I can think to do it that doesn't involve iterating over every single edge is some sort of double-nested loop that iterates over the corners of each face, and compares if there is a shared edge. Unfortunately, the way that loops have been implemented in Blender means there's no way to terminate the double-nested loop once a match has been found. I've started doing this anyways, but the node setup is a disaster and I frankly would rather not even have it if it's going to be so ugly an inelegant.

Is there a way to do this easier that doesn't involve double-nested loops? If not I might just make a custom node in my Blender fork that can do this without such a hassle.

Do you have just one pair of faces for which you want to find a common edge,  or  do you store/ calculate for each face an index of another face and want a field to get an edge for each face? BTW,  there can be up to n-2 such edges for an ngon

I only need to compare one pair of faces.

Manifold + Fields
This setup can work with fields to find multiple common edges of 2 faces. The strategy is simple: as seen in the docs of Corners of Edge topology node, there's only 2 corners (assuming manifold topology), each on a different face. So just check if 1st corner is on face A, and 2nd corner on face B, or vice-versa, 1st B and 2nd A:


Non-manifold + Fields
To support non-manifold topology (an edge can share more than 2 faces), you could use sorting to get the correct faces and confirm they were actually present:

Notice how here the cube already starts with one edge extruded into a "6" face, so that there's an edge sharing three faces 0, 1, 6; also notice how I don't check if A equals B, but that should be trivial to add.

Just a single pair
You could remove all but the 2 faces, split edges, remove edges that don't overlap and take the first one:

It doesn't actually look simpler, but for a subdiv lvl 5 Suzanne it's 3 times faster than the first solution and 4 times faster than the 2nd solution...


These are all great, thank you. I really wish that geonodes provided some way of just simply returning the index of the first element that passes some predicate check.

I believe this is also a solution for what you are after, which also includes the returning of the Index of the edge that shares the two faces, as well as the Selection of the edge.
The first group uses domain interpolation, to first create a selection for each of the faces, interpolate that onto the Edge domain (an edge will be True if it has a face that has a True attribute), then we can do the logical And to test if that edge is True for both of the input face indices.
You were also asking about getting the index of the first True element, we can do that with the Accumulate Field node and a switch input. If we have a switch node that has the Index for when something is true, then the Total output of an accumulate field node will get the index of the true item for the entire Group ID.
This will break however if we get multiple True items in a Group ID, so we can add some extra Accumulate Field nodes to ensure that we return True, only for the first time that it is true and in that Group ID and for no others.
With this setup we can get the selection, or for each Group ID the first Index where it is true as well (on the Edge domain)



Domain interpolation... of course! I do d.i. so often and yet here it didn't occur to me... I haven't tested,  but I think you don't actually need "evaluate on domain: edge" if  you use the setup in edge domain...

...And you do because you pass that through accumulate fields.

@MarkusvonBroady yep for this current setup you could drop the EOD because of the Accumulate Field, or if we were storing on edge domain etc, I like to have them there visually to be explicit but you are right that they are redundant
